# How to create new table and give color coding for difference value by subtraction of today table value from yesterday same table value on PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to automate creating the difference value table from Today table value and the Yesterday table value and also give color coding for different values in the new table.

**Yesterday Table**

```
EntityType  A Count
X            23
Y            45
Z            12
```

**Today Table**

```
EntityType  A Count
X           33
Y           46
Z           12
```

And my new table would be

[image]

My doubt is how we implement using PowerBI, we have to use DAX or any other custom option is there?

Comment: @all any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing the procedure here to get the difference between yesterday's table count and today's table count.

First, create four tables

[image]

Then we have to create the many-one(*<->1) relation between those tables

[image]

We have to create a new column difference on today table

```
CDC Change = VALUE(RELATED(yesterdayDataBucketCount[KPI_Value])-  todayDataBucketCount[KPI_Value])
```

[image]

For Color coding on the table, we have to create a rule by selecting the value

[image]

1.Number value column
[image]

2.String value column

And my new table would be

[image]